# Throw an error when a string is entered instead of an int

Tags: java, string, exception, int, java.util.scanner

I am working on homework for my class. I have written a method to throw an error if an incorrect integer is entered and I am trying to give an error message when a string is entered instead of an int but I am not sure how. I am not allowed to use parsInt or built in string methods. I would be grateful for any help.

```
int playerNum = stdin.nextInt();
while (invalidInteger(playerNum) == -1 || invalidInteger(playerNum) == -2 || invalidInteger(playerNum) == -3)
{
    if(invalidInteger(playerNum) == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid guess. Must be a positive integer.");
        System.out.println("Type your guess, must be a 4-digit number consisting of distinct digits.");
        count++;
    }
    if(invalidInteger(playerNum) == -2)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid guess. Must be a four digit integer.");
        System.out.println("Type your guess, must be a four digit number consisting of distinct digits.");
        count++;
    }
    if(invalidInteger(playerNum) == -3)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid guess. Must have distinct digits.");
        System.out.println("Type your guess, must be a four digit number consisting of distinct digits.");
        count++;
    }
    playerNum = stdin.nextInt();
}
```

Added this snippet to catch the exception. Thanks to almas shaikh.

```
try {
    int playerNum = scanner.nextInt();
    //futher code
} catch (InputMismatchException nfe) {
    System.out.println("You have entered a non numeric field value");
}
```

Comment: If you use nextInt you can't get a `String`.

Comment: Code snippets [are not for posting sample code blocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused). Use the **Code Sample { }** button instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
try {
        int playerNum = scanner.nextInt();
        //futher code
    } catch (InputMismatchException nfe) {
        System.out.println("You have entered a non numeric field value");
    }
```

Scanner throws InputMismatchException when you enter string instead of integer. So very next time when you try to enter String it will throw the InputMismatchException exception, you could catch the exception and say you let user know that user has entered invalid input and let him retry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `next()` to get the value as a `String`, then parse the value and see if a `String` or `Integer` was entered.

```
String str = stdin.next();
for (char c:str.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid character entered: " + c);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the java doc for nextInt()  -- is stdin a Scanner? If so, nextint() will throw an exception if some non-integer text is entered. You would probably want to catch that and print your own pretty error. Though, you might be going even further than the assignment expects. The phrase "throw an error if an incorrect integer is entered" might imply that only integers will be entered. It depends on the instructor/class.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            int i = in.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this will server as an example. When you give an char or string. exception is raised.